# Asp net Find parent html control of a control

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, controls

In asp net code behind I need to know the id of the parent html control of a asp control.
For example:

```
<div id="popuplogin" class="popuplogin">
     <asp:LinkButton ID="btnRegister" OnClick="btnRegister_Click1" runat="server">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
```

Now in code behind I would like to find the id of the div control which is the parent of the linkbutton (asp control).

For example:

```
protected string FindParentHtmlId(Control c)
{
    return etc..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find that `div`, you first need to add `runat=server` to be able to find it in code behind.

```
<div id="popuplogin" class="popuplogin" runat="server">
    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnRegister" runat="server">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
</div>
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
protected string FindParentHtmlId(Control c)
{
    var parent = c.Parent;

    if (parent != null)
        return parent.ID;
    else
        return "No parent found";
}
```